# UI-router - why is this controller being called?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two states that use the same template but have different controllers. The template is a form - one state is the empty form and the other is the form already filled in. I'm having trouble with one of the controllers being called from the other state.

These states are in separate modules, both being included in a module called 'products'.

Here is my code for the create screen:

```
angular.module('products.create', [])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('store.products.create', {
      url: '/create',
      parent: 'store.products',
      views: {
        'subhead@': {
          templateUrl: 'app/products/create/subhead.tmpl.html'
        },
        'content@': {
          templateUrl: 'app/products/create/create.tmpl.html',
          controller: 'ProductCreateCtrl as controller'
        }
      }
    });
  })
  .controller('ProductCreateCtrl', function() {

    var controller = this;

    // ONE INSTANCE OF THE CONTROLLER
  });
```

Here is the code the edit/show screen:

```
angular.module('products.show', [])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
      .state('store.products.show', {
        url: '/:productId',
        parent: 'store.products',
        views: {
          'subhead@': {
            templateUrl: 'app/products/show/subhead.tmpl.html'
          },
          'content@': {
            templateUrl: 'app/products/create/create.tmpl.html',
            controller: 'ProductShowCtrl as controller'
          }
        }
      });
  })
  .controller('ProductShowCtrl', function($stateParams, ProductService) {

    var controller = this;

    //THIS IS BEING CALLED IN BOTH CASES FOR SOME REASON
  });
```

Why is the show controller being called in both instances? Is there some issue with using the same template for different states?

Here the ui-view piece:

```
  <div ng-controller="ProductsCtrl">
      <div ui-view="subhead"></div>
      <div ui-view="content"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: have you tried restricting your views to their states? `content@store.products.show` and `content@store.products.create` for example? that way you make sure they don't populate other views.

Comment: That would not work. He's targeting `ui-view`s in the root template.

Comment: @HellaMedusa How do you know your other controller is being called? You're not using `ng-controller` in your template, right?

Comment: I am using ng-controller in the main html file. I'm calling a product controller, which is the controller for the module that products.show and products.create are injected in.

Comment: Just noticed something....could it be because it's interpreting /create as a valid URL for /:productId?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question in case anyone else stumbles upon something similar: The URL was being matched twice. I didn't have any regex applied to productId so /create was being interpreted as a valid product id.